# How to get a specific value out of the Terraform output

Tags: json, terraform, output

Hi I have this JSON output saved in my terraform state.
how can extract only info that I need?

If I run `terraform output -json | jq` I received the output below:

```
{
  "db_instance_address_ie": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "Service1-mysql.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
      "Service2": "Service2-mysql.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com"
    }
  },
  "grafana_alb_endpoint_ie": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "Service1-grafana-alb-xxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com",
      "Service2": "Service2-grafana-alb-xxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
    }
  },
  "grafana_private_key_ie": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxx-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
      "Service2": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxx-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
    }
  },
  "influxdb_password_ie": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "********************",
      "Service2": "********************"
    }
  },
  "mysql_password_ie": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "********************",
      "Service2": "********************"
    }
  },
  "zabbix_lb_endpoint_ie": {
    "sensitive": false,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "Service1-zbx-nlb-xxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
      "Service2": "Service2-zbx-nlb-xxxxxxxxxxxx.elb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    }
  },
  "zabbix_private_key_ie": {
    "sensitive": true,
    "type": [
      "object",
      {
        "Service1": "string",
        "Service2": "string"
      }
    ],
    "value": {
      "Service1": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxx-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
      "Service2": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----xxxxxxxx-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my full output json.

I tried to use the command below to show value, for example for :

```
terraform show -json | jq '.values.outputs.zabbix_private_key_ie[]'
```

but the output is:

```
true
{
  "Service1": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----------END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
  "Service2": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----------END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
}
[
  "object",
  {
    "Service1": "string",
    "Service2": "string"
  }
]
```

I need to extract only the values for Service1.
Is it possible?

Comment: Can you show us the exact contents of `terraform show -json` ? What you shared seems incorrect

Comment: *I need to extract only the values for Service1.* So what is the desired output?

Comment: the desired output is only the value of the private key for ```zabbix_private_key_ie``` for ```Service1```

Comment: So `jq '.zabbix_private_key_ie.value.Service1'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. I solved with this command:

```
terraform show -json | jq '.values.outputs.zabbix_private_key_ie.value.service1'
```

and the output is:

```
"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxxxxxxxx\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
```